# Google Action Intent with multiple input parameters

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm looking to POC a small Google Action that gives a decision based on a few yes/no answers the user must answer first. Effectively I need to:

1. Ask a question
2. Store the result
3. Ask the next question
4. Store results
5. * Repeat until all yes/no answers given then end the conversation with a decision using saved values in the conversation.

Ongoing though I would like to add help to any of the questions. So the user could say "I don't understand", "Can you give an example", "Help" and it would give an example to help the user answer yes or no to the question they are up to.

After playing around through the labs it looks like I would do this by creating an Intent for my end decision and then nest a bunch of follow up intents within to gather all my yes/no answers. I feel this would get messy though as it would be a huge chain of them.

Is there a better way to design it?

Comment: You can use context for that. Chain your intents with output/input contexts so users response such as "yes","no","don't understand" will only match with your aimed intent. To store response, you can use conv.user.storage on your webhook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Followup Intents would be messy. It is almost never the right approach to the problem. Remember that Intents capture *what the user has said* and not what you are doing with what they have said.

If the questions are truly just yes/no, I would setup six Intents:

- However you trigger the start of the questioning. This might be your Welcome Intent, or it may be something else.
- Saying "yes" and equivalent
- Saying "no" and equivalent
- Asking for help
- Asking to repeat the question
- A fallback Intent that handles other unexpected input

When questioning begins, your fulfillment would setup a Context that contains the current question being asked and the responses for the questions so far. Answering yes or no would update the responses, determine what question to ask next, save this in the context, and ask it. Help, repeat, and the fallback Intent would respond with appropriate information based on the current question.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner. Tried that out with one or two questions and its working ok. It might get tricky if I require yes/no responses with different fulfillments based on what task I'm completing but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it. I'm guessing I'll have to manage conversation state a little more in that case.

Comment: Exactly. Maintaining the state yourself is almost always easier than trying to craft that through followup intents. It also lets you skip questions, go back, etc.